# How to implement message sent status like whatsapp tick marks?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app. Firebase has this offline capabilities. Even if I am offline the sent text messages are shown as sent.

Is it possible in any way to show two states? One when the user has sent the message from the app and the other when the message gets written to the database. Any help will be appreciated.

This is how I write to the database:

```
mChatSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = mChatMessageView.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){

                    String user_ref = "Announcement/"+email_red+"/"+class_id;

                    DatabaseReference user_message_push = mRootRef.child("Announcement")
                            .child(email_red).child(class_id).push();

                    String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

                    Map messageMap = new HashMap();
                    messageMap.put("Message", message);
                    messageMap.put("Type", 1);

                    Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
                    messageUserMap.put(user_ref+"/"+push_id,messageMap)

                    mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError!=null){

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell when a write to the database succeeds by using the callback method on the update.  You're using one right here, but you're not doing anything in it:

```
mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError!=null){

        }
    }
});
```

When the above `onComplete` is called, that's how you know the write of `messageUserMap` finished successfully on the server.